# How to create a bar-chart in android using web services?

Tags: android, web-services, bar-chart

How to create a bar-chart in android?

**NOTE : -**
*But i need to use the x-axis and y-axis values from the web service.*
Which means that web service is going to show the x and y axis values.Bythen i need to use those values as x and y axis values for creating a bar-chart.

How to do this?Suggestions please.

**LOGCAT**

```
09-21 15:09:53.103: D/AndroidRuntime(271): Shutting down VM
09-21 15:09:53.103: W/dalvikvm(271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlparsing_test/com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.buildBarDataset(BarGraphActivity.java:115)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.DrawGraph(BarGraphActivity.java:57)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.onCreate(BarGraphActivity.java:22)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-21 15:09:53.114: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  ... 11 more
09-21 15:10:04.033: I/Process(271): Sending signal. PID: 271 SIG: 9
```

**chart.java**

```
 public class Chart extends Activity 
 {      
    EditText edt1,edt2;
TextView txtv1;
Button btn;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(),edt2.getText().toString());

    Intent intnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), BarGraphActivity.class);
            startActivity(intnt);
        }
    });
    }
public void getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate) 
   {
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetTMSChart"; 
    String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD); 

    request.addProperty("FromDate","");               
    request.addProperty("ToDate","");

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
        int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

     for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
     {           
        //String ord = table.getPropertyAsString("");

         int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
         int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
         int marginPercent =     Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{}
}   }
```

**BarGraphActivity.java**

```
public class BarGraphActivity extends Chart
{   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    DrawGraph();
   }
Chart ch = new Chart();


 public void DrawGraph() 
 {

String[] titles = new String[] { " Barcharts",""};

int[] x_axis =null;   
int[] y_axis =null;

List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
values.add(x_axis);
values.add(y_axis);

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
setChartSettings(renderer, "some texts", " ", " ",0,x_axis, 0,y_axis, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

renderer.setXLabels(1);
renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "orderNo");
renderer.addYTextLabel(2, "freight");
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);

int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
  SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
  seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
  }

    ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
  }

public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{
    // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

 renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
 renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
 renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
 renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

 int length = colors.length;
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
 {
   SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
   r.setColor(colors[i]);
   renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
   }

 public void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,String yTitle, int xMin, int[] x_axis, int yMin, int[] y_axis, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
 {
    // sets lots of default values for this renderer

renderer.setChartTitle(title);

renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);

renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<int[]> values) 
 {
    // adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

int length = titles.length;

 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
 {
   CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);

   int[] v = values.get(i);

   int seriesLength = v.length;

   for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
   {
     series.add(v[k]);
    }

   dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
   }
   return dataset;
  } }
```

thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: What is the problem? - You can straight away write one AsyncTask in doInBackground call WS and Parse data into two ArrayList and then Pass that array list in onPostExecute of asynctask and there using those two arraylist create your chart.

Comment: @MKJParekh Actually i have tried,as like you suggest.But i am getting some null pointer exception on my logcat.

Comment: Debug your code also give respect to logcat error messages read it carefully and you will surely get the root of error.

Answer (score 2):

1- Get values from web service.

This has really nothing to do with the bar chart. Just call the web service and get the values you need.

2- Once you have the values you can create a bar chart using [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/).

**EDIT:**

Upon reading your update here are my general thoughts.

In `chart.java`, you are calling the web service and reading the values into local variables, therefore those values aren't being stored anywhere.

In `BarGraphActivity.DrawGraph()`, `x_axis` and `y_axis` are always `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

The solution:

In your first activity collect your values in `int` arrays and send them in the Intent when you start your second activity.

In the latter, retrieve the arrays and pass them to `DrawGraph()`.

*One more note:* You are calling the web service on the main thread, which is not advisable. You should move it into the `doInBackground()` method of an `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: please visit my question again i have given my logcat for reference

Comment: Actually i am getting the values from the web service perfectly,but the way i am parsing to the bar-chart is wrong i think.?

Comment: Please post your `onCreate()` and `DrawGraph()` methods.

Comment: Please visit my question again i have given onCreate() and DrawGraph() for reference.

Comment: Benito can you tell me what mistake i am committing on my project?

Comment: Benito,now i am following your suggestion,i am getting some errors when trying to collect the values on array list

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some bad XML to me.  Your parser gave you a `NullPointerException`.

I don't know which parser your Android code is using, SAX or DOM.  I don't know if the service you called sent back XML raw or wrapped in a SOAP envelope.  I don't know if you're using a SOAP client that knows how to extract the payload from the SOAP envelope.  I don't know what you're doing with your data once you have it.

But you should.

Comment: I am using SOAP method to consume that web service.I can able to get the values from the web service but i am getting some errors while parsing those values to the bar-chart.